# Even after adding a column to a dataframe my shape remains the same which means I am not able to add a column to my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, multiple-columns

This is my piece of code:

```
def segregate_files(self, list_of_csv, each_sub_folder):

    new_list_of_csv = []
    for each_csv in list_of_csv:
        pattern = f"{each_sub_folder}/(.*?)/"
        self.data_centre = re.search(pattern, each_csv).group(1)
        if "org_dashboards/" in each_csv:
            each_csv = each_csv.replace("org_dashboards/", f"{self.file_path}/")
        else:
            each_csv = each_csv.replace("dashboards/", f"{self.file_path}/")
        df = pd.read_csv(each_csv)
        print(df.shape)
        df["Data Centre"] = self.data_centre
        print(df.shape)
        df.to_csv(each_csv)
        new_list_of_csv.append(each_csv)
        # self.list_of_sub_folder.append(f"files/{blob_name}")
    print(new_list_of_csv)
    self.aggregate_csv_path = f"{self.file_path}/{each_sub_folder}"
    return new_list_of_csv, self.aggregate_csv_path
```

and my dataframe is properly able to read the csv
and there is no error in df["Data Centre"] = self.data_centre
only the shape remains the same
FYI the value of self.data_centre is also correct

Comment: It would be good if you can provide head() values and self.data_centre

Comment: Sorry I cannot provide the head() values but self.data_centre = 'firewalls'

Comment: but I am getting the values of df.head()

Comment: If you can't post the head values, perhaps df.dtypes(in the answer above). I mean the column should get added to your data frame so, just to be sure what does the shape prints both times?

Comment: it prints the same value

Comment: i.e. (4274, 52)

Comment: Okay, it could be that your data frame already has a  column named 'Data Centre'. Kindly verify that too.

Comment: No this is also not the case.I have already checked it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my bad. It was a file write issue. Now it has been resolved. Thank you.